# Does anyone know why Swiper JS Pagination bullets are stretching on iOS devices?

Tags: ios, pagination, slider, mobile-safari, swiper.js

The swiper js pagination dots look and function perfectly on desktop chrome and safari browsers, but when on my iPad, or iPhone safari browser, the pagination dots stretch out, ignoring width/height/min-height rules. Has anyone else experienced this and have a fix? I've attached some examples for reference.

[Dots on iOS safari browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4d8bV.jpg)

I tried setting width and height css as page-styles as an html-embed (I'm working in webflow). I tried taking the swiper sliders outside of my page sections, to see if there was some kind of forced width occuring on those sections, but the issue still remained. I added the following style tag to my page head (see below), but also didn't seem to fix the issue.

```
"<style>
.swiper-pagination-bullets.swiper-pagination-horizontal {
width: auto;
}
</style>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Webflow and Had this issue as well, IDK how this fixes it but it does for me.
(this sites being annoying and wouldn't let me post the code so you'll need to fill in the . and the : and the ; and the style)

swiper-bullet
max-widt: 16px !important
max-height 16px !important
padding 0px !important

IDK if the max width and height do anything but I know the padding 0px important does.

Comment: This worked!  Thank you so much, this was bothering me for weeks.